# Has a Gaussian Mixture Model ever been fit to a geographical map? If so, is there a reference?

Tags: statistics, geospatial, spatial, gaussian-mixture-model

This can't be a novel idea, but I'm having a hard time finding this being done before. So, I have a geographical map with "things" happening on it. I can show this map color coded such that the red areas are with more happenings, and white areas with nothing going on. These data show clustering, and I'd like to fit these happenings with a GMM, such that I overlay each component to a region of the map. Has this been done before? Thanks in advance!